# Create tables in Oracle the same as they are in Postgres

Tags: oracle, pentaho, ddl

I have multiple Tables in PostgreSQL

`extract_a, extract_b` and so on now I want to create all of these tables in Oracle by using Pentaho.

I set the Data type `Varchar2(4000)` in all my tables fields. Tables created successfully but when I tried to insert the data it give men an error

> "Identifier is too long"

How do I create these tables Oracle ?

Comment: "identifier is too long" has nothing to do with "data types". It it what it says: your table (or column names) are too long. Oracle only supports up to 30 characters. If you have table (or column) names longer than 30 characters, you need to use shorter names in Oracle.

Comment: yes i did the same which you said.. 
I minimize the all column name which is longer.. and pentaho create table successfully. but issue at the time of insertion..

Comment: What is the SQL statement that is generating the error?

Comment: Look at your insert statements then. Look for an identifier that is longer than 30 characters.

Comment: This is how my table create  in pentaho
CREATE TABLE extract_O
(
  If_entry_no VARCHAR2(2000)
, Intfe_ctr_flg_key VARCHAR2(2000)
, Record_type_key VARCHAR2(2000)
, Line_id VARCHAR2(2000)
, Units VARCHAR2(2000)
, Salesperson VARCHAR2(2000)
, Merchndis_des VARCHAR2(2000)
, Expctnd_delivry_on VARCHAR2(2000)
, Color_desc VARCHAR2(2000)
, Size_desc VARCHAR2(2000)
, Width_des VARCHAR2(2000)
, Vendor_name VARCHAR2(2000)
, Vndr_styl_des VARCHAR2(2000)
, Specal_ordr_clas_des VARCHAR2(2000)
, Vendor_no VARCHAR2(2000)
, extract_filename VARCHAR2(100)
)TABLESPACE DAA03_stagging;